# I am very green when it comes to node.js integration

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

So I figured the best way to learn is to try and fail over and over. I am building a webapp, at least trying to. I am curious how to go about using node to query my db. I am able to make a connection to the db with my single app.js file.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'xxxxxxxx-us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
        port      :  '3306',
        user     : 'user',
        password : 'password',
        database : 'app'
});
connection.connect(function(err){

    if(!err) {
        console.log("Database is connected ... ");    
    } else {
        console.log("Error connecting database ... ");    
    }
});
```

My problem, or lack of understand begins when I try to integrate this into my client-side js code. For instance say I wanted to trigger the db connection when a user uploads a photo.

```
var upload = s3.putObject({
            Bucket: albumBucketName,
            Key: photoKey,
            Body: file,
            ACL: "public-read",
        });

        var promise = upload.promise();
```

Can I include the app.js node file?
Sorry if this is a dumb question. I feel like I am missing some fundamental understanding of how to integrate the functionality of node with my current client side JS. Any help or further reading is appreciated--I am even curious about PHP solutions. 
X

Comment: NodeJS and its backend code runs on a server, clientside Javascript runs in a client's browser. They don't share any code whatsoever and they communicate through HTTP/WebSockets/etc. You can use a framework like Express to easily build an API in Node for your clientside JS to consume. All of the code provided is intended to run on backend (NodeJS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server and client side code are separate. However you can create a Node module that harnesses the AWS and returns an appropriate response to the client after completed.

To do this, you need to create an endpoint that you post your data to from the client, then process with the same AWS modules only for Node. You also need to be able to access the `connection` instance from a different NodeJS module. This can be accomplished several ways. First, if the library that instantiates the connection tracks all of the connections, you should be able to require the library in a different module, then use the library's API to access one of the connections. Second, if you create only one instance of the connection and allow it to export, then you can import the module with that connection. Third, you can use something like a `request/response` pattern between the two modules, with the pattern instance declared globally.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful answer i'll try to reconfigure based on your model.